# Save and restore for a CNN based Denoising Network Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

My question is about restoring the Denoised Trained Model.
I have my network defined in the following way.

Conv1->relu1->Conv2->relu2->Conv3->relu3->Deconv1

The tf.variable_scope(name) is same as above.

Now I have my *loss*, *optimizer* and *accuracy* defined with tf.name_scope.

When I try to restore *loss* function, It will ask even for *labels* (which I don't have).

```
feed_dict={x:input, y:labels}
sess.run('loss',feed_dict)
```

Can anyone please help me understand how to test this? Which operation should I restore ?

Should I have to call all layers, pass the input and check the loss(MSE)?

I checked many examples but it seems to be all Classification problem and defining softmax with logits at last works.

**Edit:**
Below is my code and now it is easily visible how tf.name_scope and tf.variable_scope is defined. I feel I may have to bring whole layer to test new Image. Is that right?

```
def new_conv_layer(input, num_input_channels, filter_size, num_filters, name):

with tf.variable_scope(name):
    # Shape of the filter-weights for the convolution
shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]


    # Create new weights (filters) with the given shape
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters], stddev=0.5))


    # Create new biases, one for each filter
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[num_filters]))

    filters = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters], stddev=0.5))


    # TensorFlow operation for convolution
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filter=filters, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

    # Add the biases to the results of the convolution.
    layer += biases

    return layer, weights

def new_relu_layer(input, name):

 with tf.variable_scope(name):
    #TensorFlow operation for convolution
    layer = tf.nn.relu(input)

    return layer
def new_pool_layer(input, name):

 with tf.variable_scope(name):


    # TensorFlow operation for convolution
    layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=input, ksize=[1, 1, 1, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    return layer 

def new_layer(inputs, filters,kernel_size,strides,padding, name):

 with tf.variable_scope(name):

    layer = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs=inputs, filters=filters , kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding,   data_format =  'channels_last')

    return layer







layer_conv1, weights_conv1 = new_conv_layer(input=yTraininginput, num_input_channels=1, filter_size=5, num_filters=32, name ="conv1")
layer_relu1 = new_relu_layer(layer_conv1, name="relu1")

layer_conv2, weights_conv2 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_relu1, num_input_channels=32, filter_size=5, num_filters=64, name ="conv2")
layer_relu2 = new_relu_layer(layer_conv2, name="relu2")


layer_conv3, weights_conv3 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_relu2, num_input_channels=64, filter_size=5, num_filters=128, name ="conv3")
layer_relu3 = new_relu_layer(layer_conv3, name="relu3")


layer_deconv1 = new_layer(inputs=layer_relu3, filters=1,  kernel_size=[5,5] ,strides=[1,1] ,padding='same',name = 'deconv1')
layer_relu4 = new_relu_layer(layer_deconv1, name="relu4")


layer_conv4, weights_conv4 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_relu4, num_input_channels=1, filter_size=5, num_filters=128, name ="conv4")
layer_relu5 = new_relu_layer(layer_conv4, name="relu5")


layer_deconv2 = new_layer(inputs=layer_relu5, filters=1,  kernel_size=[5,5] ,strides=[1,1] ,padding='same',name = 'deconv2')
layer_relu6 = new_relu_layer(layer_deconv2, name="relu6")





# Use Cross entropy cost function
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels = xTraininglabel,predictions = layer_relu6)


# Use Adam Optimizer
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-6).minimize(loss = cross_entropy)


# Accuracy
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    accuracy = tf.image.psnr(a=layer_relu6,b=xTraininglabel,max_val=1.0)
```

Comment: Hey Krish! Could you possibly provide more context to your question to help people answer your question better? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  I would do it

Comment: In this case, the "labels" are the ground-truth images that you want your denoiser to output, xTrainingLabel in your code. If you don't have labels because you want your network to output its input, the input should be the "label". To me the question is a little unclear.

Comment: I have a noisy image(input) to test for the trained model. Labels are used during the training process. 
Now because of data issue, I have only (new)input, not the corresponding labels.
This is supervised learning

Comment: What should i really restore to test my model?

>Loss layer (MSE) gives one number can't use

>Accuracy(PSNR)?

>Optimizer?

>Last layer relu? I'm confused with these things

Comment: And don't I have to restore relu and pooling layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to view the graph of your code on tensorboard, get the operation name from the last layer(in your case deconv4). Something like below image.
Try loading the tensor, using below code:

```
operation = graph.get_tensor_by_name("<operationname:0>")
```

This should work, as your layers are interconnected.

Let me know if this worked!

[Operation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EENB8.jpg)

Comment: This works but if I do the following thing, how will I make sure if its passing through all the layers ?? As my dimension of last and first are same

Comment: By checking Accuracy of trained network? Or build a small network and check?